# SwiftUI realm database Issue passing the fetched data to another view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, realm, crud

I'm using realm database and I had issue after fetching for the data for a list and use on tap gesture property  to go to the detail view it's only show the first set of data in my realm database.
I will show some pictures to illustrate.
[image]

this is how my list look like

[image]

and this is detail view when clicked and it's only showing the first set of data whatever what you clicked on.

```
 ForEach(realmManger.patterns, id: \.id) { userPattern in
                                
patternCell(title: userPattern.title ?? "Error??", date: userPattern.dateCreated ?? Date.now)
.onTapGesture {
 editPattern = true
}.sheet(isPresented: $editPattern) {
patternEdit(userPattern: userPattern)
  .environmentObject(realmManger)
  }
}
```

the code is too long I tried to show what important

```
struct patternEdit: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var realmManger:RealmManger
    @State var showAlert = false
    
    let userPattern:Patterns
    
    var body: some View {
   
                Text(userPattern.title ?? "Error")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("lightBlue"))
                    .padding()

}
```

and this is the code for the detail view why is it only showing the first data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `.sheet()` out of the `ForEach` loop and use the `.sheet(item: ...)`,
like in this example code using  `@State var selectedPattern: ...`

```
 @State var selectedPattern: Patterns?  // <-- here
 // ...
 
 var body: some View {
     // ...
     ForEach(realmManger.patterns, id: \.id) { userPattern in
         patternCell(title: userPattern.title ?? "Error??", date: userPattern.dateCreated ?? Date.now)
             .onTapGesture {
                 selectedPattern = userPattern  // <-- here
             }
     }
     .sheet(item: $selectedPattern) { userPattern in  // <-- here
         patternEdit(userPattern: userPattern)
             .environmentObject(realmManger)
     }
 // ...
 }
```

Adjust the example code to suit your purpose.